# How to parallel this two loop using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

Is this the correct way to parallel two for loops by using the "#pragma omp single nowait" and "#pragma omp for for two different loops"? Or is there any other way to do it?

```
#pragma omp single nowait
{
for (i = ; i < N; i += )
{
D[i] = x * A[i] + x * B[i]; 
}
#pragma omp for
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
C[i] = c * D[i];
}
} // end omp parallel
```

Comment: You may want to use some temporary variables to help the compiler recognize patterns.  For example:  `temp1 = x * A[i]; temp2 = x  B[i]; D[i] = temp1 + temp2;`  Many processors have instructions that can multiply a vector by a scalar quantity.

Comment: You may be getting some data cache issue because the processor can't load all 3 arrays into its cache at the same time (for the first `for` loop).  Changing the data structure to an array of  `struct` with `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` members may be faster because `A[i], B[i], C[i], D[i]` can all be on the same cache line, reducing the number of data cache reloads.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a better problem description. As is the program even contradicts itself in the comments.

Comment: With the separate loops as written with nowait, it is incorrect, as the second loop may sometimes access an element of D before it has been updated in the first loop.  Combining them will save cache thrashing, more so if C[] is compiled for non-temporal stores

Answer (score 0):

You should note that you can actually merge the two for loops into one...since for each i, you compute D[i], and later on, the computation for C[i] is just dependent on D[i].

you should combine the loops that way, and then just use omp for as you did for your second loop.